# How Do I Integrate? $\int \frac{-2x^{2}+6x+8}{x^{2}(x+2)}$

Tags: calculus, integration

How do I integrate this one? $$\int \frac{-2x^{2}+6x+8}{x^{2}(x+2)}\,dx$$
Is my answer correct: $$-3\ln\left \| x+2 \right \|+\ln\left \| x \right \|+\frac{4}{x}+C$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partial fraction decomposition.

$$\dfrac{-2x^2 + 6x +8}{x^2(x + 2)} = \dfrac{A}{x}+ \dfrac{B}{x^2} + \dfrac{C}{x+2}$$

Solve for $A, B, C$.

Your almost there with your answer, but we need $-\frac 4x$, and $\ln |x| - 3\ln|x+2| = \ln\left|\dfrac{x}{(x+2)^3}\right|$, if you want to simplify further.

Comment: yup, I already solved for A,B,and C. but I am not confident of my answer because when I inputted the equation on wolfram, it generated a different answer.

Comment: Note that the terms with ln can be simplified by log rules, so Wolfram may have output a simplification of your answer. Also note the missing negative sign for the term $\frac{4}{x}$

Comment: oh right. But how come $\frac{4}{x}$ becomes negative when the value of B is +4? can you please clarify it for me?

Comment: Because the power rule. Integrating $\dfrac 4{x^2} = 4x^{-2}$ gives us $\dfrac{4x^{-1}}{-1} = -4x^{-1} = \dfrac {-4}{x}$

Answer (score 2):

Express in partial fractions:

$$\frac{8 + 6x - 2x^{2}}{x^{2}(x + 2)} = \frac{4}{x^{2}} + \frac{1}{x} - \frac{3}{x + 2}$$

Integrate term by term:

$$\int \frac{4}{x^{2}} + \frac{1}{x} - \frac{3}{x + 2} \ \mathrm{d}x = -\frac{4}{x} + \ln{|x|} - 3\ln{|x + 2|} + C$$

So you are missing a negative sign.

Comment: so, is this also your answer?

Comment: Yes that is my answer, it is slightly different to yours. Notice I have $-\frac{4}{x}$ rather than $+\frac{4}{x}$.